# Is there any way to turn off tail recursion optimization of Scala Compiler?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

For some special reasons, I want to remove the effect of all @tailrec in a big program, but don't want to do that manually, is there any optional arguments when compiling that can turn off the tail recursion optimization? I want to just leave the @tailrec in the code, but don't want to check it and do tail recursion optimization when compiling. Is that possible?

Comment: It is *extremely* unclear what you are asking. First, you say you want to remove all `@tailrec` annotations, later you say you want to leave them in. Which is it? Also, you talk about turning off tail recursion optimization, which is completely unrelated to the `@tailrec` annotation.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. I mean "leave @tailrec in the code but eliminate their effects"

Comment: The *only* effect the `@tailrec` annotation has is that the compiler will tell you if the code is tail-recursive or not. So, you *still* want your code to get tailrec optimized, you only don't want to be told about code that isn't tail-recursive?

Comment: I don't want the compiler issue the error when a function with @tailrec isn't tail recursion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can use the compiler's `-g:notailcalls` option.**

From the docs:

> -g:{none,source,line,vars,notailcalls}
>
> "none" generates no debugging info,
>
> "source" generates only the source file attribute,
>
> "line" generates source and line number information,
>
> "vars" generates source, line number and local variable information,
>
> "notailcalls" generates all of the above and **will not perform tail call optimization**.

Note, as the docs specify, that **this will also enable debug info generation**.

---

An example:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

class A {

@tailrec
final def x(i: Int): Int = if(i == 0) {i;} else {x(i-1)}

}
```

`javap -p -v A.class` of `x` when compiled "normally":

```
public final int x(int);
    descriptor: (I)I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: iload_1
         1: iconst_0
         2: if_icmpne     7
         5: iload_1
         6: ireturn
         7: iload_1
         8: iconst_1
         9: isub
        10: istore_1
        11: goto          0
```

The same, when compiled with `-g:notailcalls`:

```
public final int x(int);
    descriptor: (I)I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: iload_1
         1: iconst_0
         2: if_icmpne     9
         5: iload_1
         6: goto          16
         9: aload_0
        10: iload_1
        11: iconst_1
        12: isub
        13: invokevirtual #12                 // Method x:(I)I
        16: ireturn
```

The important bit is the `invokevirtual` on position `13`.

---

Note, by the way, that jwvh prudently corrected you on the interpetation of `@tailrec` - it doesn't actually toggle tail optimization, the only thing that it does is that it informs the compiler to fail if it cannot insert a tail call optimization, **which it would attempt anyway**.

Answer (score 3):

The `@tailrec` annotation doesn't turn on/off tail recursion optimization.  It only tells the compiler to error out if the annotated routine is **not** properly tail recursive.

If the routine is tail recursive then the optimization is there whether it's annotated or not.

From the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.annotation.tailrec):

> A method annotation which verifies that the method will be compiled
>   with tail call optimization.
>
> If it is present, the compiler will issue an error if the method
>   cannot be optimized into a loop.

The operative word being "verifies".

**UPDATE**

@mikołak is correct.  A quick check shows that the `-g:notailcalls` flag turns off annotation verification.

```
%%> scalac tailrec.scala 
tailrec.scala:5: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method rf: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
def rf(x: Int): Int = if (x < 1) x else rf(x-2)+1
                                               ^
one error found
%%> scalac -g:notailcalls tailrec.scala 
%%>
```

Comment: Thank you, but, I mean that is there a way that we can ignore the @tailrec when compiling? Does scala compiler provide us an option?

Comment: Oh, you mean you want to tell the compiler, "please ignore the @tailrec annotations. I don't care if any are not truly tail recursive."

Hmm, that's a good question.

Comment: I think the OP wants to stop the compiuler doing tail recursion optimisation at all (presumably to get a meaningful stack trace). That's what the title of the question says, anyway

Comment: Upvoting this anyway since OP is clearly confused on what `@tailrec` actually does.